# Why do I get "Operator "==" cannot be applied to operands of type "char" and "string"" when if statement check whether word contains letter "e"?

Tags: c#, operator-keyword

In this program, I want to load a text file containing words. I then go ahead and check though each word if they contain the letter "e". If so, I replace the letter "e" with a 3, otherwise I don't change the letter. I then, proceed to write a new file with the modified words.

My problem is that, in the 'if' condition check, I get "Operator "==" cannot be applied to operands of type "char" and "string"". I think, maybe I cannot perform an operation as '==' on a char and a substring number. So, how would I go about remedying this. Thank you!

```
public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine ("Please enter location of the text file to leet: ");

        string myFirstFilePath = Console.ReadLine ();
        string[] firstFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines (myFirstFilePath);

        int wordCount = 0;
        ArrayList mixedList = new ArrayList();

        System.Console.WriteLine ("Please enter location of where you would like the new text file to be saved: ");
        string newFileDestination = Console.ReadLine ();

        TextWriter writeToNewFile = new StreamWriter (newFileDestination);
        foreach (string one in firstFile) {
            string word;
            for (int i = 0; i <= one.Length; i++) {
                if (one[i] == "e") {
                    word = word + "3";
                } else {
                    word = word + word.Substring(i);
                    writeToNewFile.WriteLine (one);
                    wordCount++;
                }
            }
        }
        writeToNewFile.Close ();
        Console.WriteLine (wordCount);
        Console.WriteLine ("Press any key to exit.");
        System.Console.ReadKey ();
     }
```

Comment: if `one[i] == 'e'` note single quotes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'char' and 'string'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033642/operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-char-and-string)

Comment: Copying your question title into google results in [thousands of duplicates](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=Operator+%E2%80%9C%3D%3D%E2%80%9D+cannot+be+applied+to+operands+of+type+%E2%80%9Cchar%E2%80%9D+and+%E2%80%9Cstring%E2%80%9D). Please read [ask] and show effort in your questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `one[i] == "e"` with `one[i] == 'e'`.

Using double quote invoke `string` type, whereas using single quote invoke `char` type

---

Furthermore, you declare `string word;` and use it (`word = word + "3"`) without assign it. I recommend assign it to avoid potential side effect : `string word = "";`

Comment: You are right, that worked. Noobish mistake. Thanks for your time in answering!

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the "e" to single quotes 'e'. Single quotes are used to denote a character, whereas double denotes a string.

e.g. From:

```
if (one[i] == "e")
```

to:

```
if (one[i] == 'e')
```

Answer (score 2):

The immediate reason of the error is that

```
  "e" - string
  'e' - char (note single quotes)
```

and since `one[i]` returns `char`, the solution is

```
  if (one[i] == 'e')
```

Answer (score 2):

The String is the character's array. To compare a char data type, you should compare it with the specific element of string (i.e. a single char) not with whole string.

As

```
if (one[i] == 'e') \\ not like, if (one[i] == "e")
```